# jquery ui autocomplete how to load a default value list

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

very simple question (but I can't find the answer on the Web...): I have an autocomplete field being set this way:

```
$(document).ready ->
         $('#projecttask_user_name').autocomplete
                 source: "/autocomplete/users"
```

I would like jquery to trigger the source when I select the field in order to get the full list of possibilities even if I haven't typed anything in the field.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the [minLength](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength) option to `0`, and call the [search](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search) method when the input element gains focus:

```
$("#projecttask_user_name").autocomplete({
    source: "/autocomplete/users",
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);
});
```